# How to set a <div> to toggle it's own size using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to have a  element toggle it's own size using jquery... However it behaves rather strangely, when I click it the first time it expands (brilliant) However when I click it again I wan't it to go back to it's original size, however it goes back to it's original size and then expands again... on the third click it does the same... 4th it contracts, expands, contracts, then expands again... and so on!

Is there any way of avoiding this, i'm guessing it is because it interprets a click on the large box as a click on the large and a click on the small?

Here's my code :)

```
$(document).ready(function(    
$("#box").click(function(){
 $("#box").toggle(function(){
        $("#box").animate({width:960},"fast","swing");
        $("#box").animate({height:500},"fast","swing");},
    function(){
        $("#box").animate({height:20},"fast","swing");
        $("#box").animate({width:20},"fast","swing");
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggle` is a click handler. You don't need to wrap it in `click`: it's done for you. In fact, you're rebinding the `toggle` code every time the element is clicked, hence the increasing numbers.

```
$(document).ready(function (
$("#box").toggle(function () {
    $(this).animate({width: 960}, "fast", "swing");
    $(this).animate({height: 500}, "fast", "swing");
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({height: 20}, "fast", "swing");
    $(this).animate({width: 20}, "fast", "swing");
});
});
```

Note that I have changed the repeated `#box` calls to `this`, which is far faster. I could also have changed the two sets of two lines into two single `animate`calls (`.animate({width: 960, height: 500})`) but the difference in behaviour might be desired...

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Yes the difference in behaviour was required however the 'this' is helpful! I've only just started off with jQuery so any help is massively appreciated :D